# Words Randomly Disappearing From Dictionary

Tags: 8.1, dictionary

Certain words in my dictionary (e.g. "th" for "the") are randomly disappearing. They will no longer work with WordFlow; I must type them manually. And then they are underlined in red. If I press the + to add it to the dictionary it acts like it added it, but it still is red/doesn't work. And I can try to add it again... and again... It simply won't add it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you checked that you didn't change the keyboard language by accident?

Comment: No, it's set to English.

Comment: have you tried resetting the dictionary?

Comment: I have had WP for almost a year now and have been through 2 phones, with multiple dictionary resets, phone resets, and upgrades. I have always had the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug. Microsoft is trying to fix this but don't know if they really are or not.

Comment: Could you cite your source for this information so the rest of us can check it out?